# On cell referencing in google sheets, clarification needed

Tags: google-sheets, reference

- On sheet `Summary`, I have a cell `A1`  that has a value "AAPL"
- On sheet `AAPL`,    I have a cell `X22` that has a value "123"

In order for me to display "123", I do `=AAPL!X22`. Pretty straightforward.

**How can I rewrite this using A1 value? In other words instead of hardcoding AAPL, I would like to express .. whatever is in A1 cell**

I tried

- `=&A1!X22` but this didn't work.

Thank you for your time

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en - use INDIRECT.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("D30")!X22`, doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: I think you want `=INDIRECT(D30&"!X22")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en). Enclose the `!X22` in quotes and do not put quotes around the reference to the cell containing `AAPL` (in your question `A1`, or in the comments `D30`):

```
=INDIRECT(D30&"!X22")
```